# Prolog: can we pass a fact as argument to another fact?

Tags: prolog

I have a rule where I have to check whether a person who works for a department also works for its college and the university. The sample knowledge base is the following:

```
university(xxx). /*the university*/
col(scienceAndMath,xxx). /*the college of the university*/
dept_col(biology,scienceAndMath). /*the department of the college*/
dept_faculty(michael,biology). /*the faculty member of the department*/
```

I have to make a rule, namely `works_for(X,Y)` to check that an individual who works for a department, also works for its college and the university. I am trying to do this in the following manner, but to no avail.

```
works_for(X,Y):-dept_faculty(X,Y).  
works_for(X,Y):-dept_col(works_for(X,Y),Y).
/*also tried works_for(X,Y):-dept_col(dept_faculty(X,Y),Y)./*
```

For example, for the query `works_for(michael,X).`, the result should be following:

```
X = biology
X = scienceAndMath
```

How do I pass a fact as argument to another fact? At present, the answer of the query is the following:

```
X = biology
false.
```

Comment: Can you explain in your own words why you expect `works_for(X,Y):-dept_col(works_for(X,Y),Y).` to work?

Comment: Why do you think you need to pass a fact as an argument to achieve your goal of the conjunctive query? That's not really how Prolog works to achieve what you're after. You're thinking of predicates as if they were functions, which they are not. The conjunction you're describing looks like `works_for(X, Y) :- works_for(X, Z), dept_col(Z, Y).` This literally means *`X` works for `Y` if `X` works for `Z` and `Z` is a department of college `Y`*.

Comment: You can, in Prolog, pass a *term* as an argument. Everything in Prolog is a term. So you could say, `foo(Pred, Res) :- call(Pred, Z), bar(Z, Res).` and call, `foo(bah(X), Y).` where `bah/2` is defined (note that `call(Pred, Z)` will pass `Z` as the final argument to `Pred`, so it will call `bah(X, Z)` in this case). But that's definitely not the correct approach to solving this particular problem.

Comment: @lurer: Thanks. What if I want to extend it to the university? For example, A works in a department B, B is in a college C, and C is in the university D.